# How to avoid unnecessary construction of std::vector<Base *>

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have two classes

```
class Base{ ... };

class Derived : public Base { ... };
```

and some other function which operates and modifies a collection of `Base` pointers:

```
void foo(std::vector<Base *> ptrs_to_base);
```

I have a `std::vector<Derived>` which holds my data. To pass it to `foo` I can construct a new vector of type `std::vector<Base *>` containing all pointers. In many situations this will be the easiest thing to do. However, I don't like the overhead with which it comes and in some situations it is simply not affordable to allocate dynamic memory.

**Is there a way to change `foo`'s interface as to do everything in place? In principle there should be no need for unnecessary construction of collections.** I know there is no easy way, so usage of additional (multi-purpose) helper classes would be fine.

For example

```
template <typename Iter>
void foo(Iter begin, Iter end) {
   //*begin is of type Base*
   ...
}

std::vector<Derived> elements;
std::vector<Derived *> ptrs_to_elements = ... // construct from elements
foo(ptrs_to_elements.begin(), ptrs_to_elements.end());
```

would be one solution which requires templates and doesn't make it obvious that only pointers of type `Base *` are required. Edit: W.F. gave a way to recognize wrong usages of this template. It still requires the unnecessary  construction of `ptrs_to_elements`.

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pKf297Hwutt2Uuws)?

Comment: PS. prefer smart pointers over raw ones...

Comment: @W.F. Great! I didn't know about this feature. This improves the template based approach. I the case I only have a `std::vector<Derived>` it doesn't suffice, though. Any ideas there?

Comment: @W.F. concerning the smart pointers: In this case I want to use raw pointers as they convey the notion that ownership is not transferred by passing the objects to `foo`.

Comment: I think in the case you want to support both values and pointers I think you won't be able to deal without overloading `foo` I'm afraid  :( unless you are using c++17 and have no problem with using `if constexpr`

Comment: @W.F I realized that my last example was confusing. I only want to call `foo` with some ptr-like type. I.e. no copying of neither `Base` nor `Derived` should be required. In fact, I want to iterate over `std::vector<Derived>` and treat its elements as something like `Base *`.

Comment: well to treat `Derived` as pointer to `Derived` you could always overload dereference operator in your `Derived` like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RN6xzYXo6BmG3iIP). Be careful though with this approach to not to dereference `Derived` temporary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your function takes a vector as parameter. And vector as any other standard container does not implement a simple interface and is not intended to be derived.

That means that if you only have a vector of objects and need a vector of pointers your only choice is to build a new vector.

For that reason, standard C++ container are very good to store objects, but public interface should rather use... interfaces of simple wrappers around them to make *on flight transformation* easier (if not simply just possible)

Comment: Thanks! So in my example what kind of wrapper would I have?